# Connecting to mysql using management tool

Tags: mysql

So far I have set up my MySQL database only in the terminal using a homebrew.

Now I want to connect to the database and access all of its tables using Sequel Pro, which is a database management tool.

I'm wondering how I can connect to my local database that I have created on my terminal; Sequel Pro gives three types of ways you can connect : standard, socket, and ssh.  I'm not sure which I should select.

Answer (score 0):

Socket implies that client and server are on the same machine.

SSH is for security.

So, try "standard".